# WPF Scrollviewer shrink height, bring element into view

Tags: c#, wpf

First off, the title might not make much sense. Suggestions for changing it are appreciated.

I am clicking into a `TextBox` that is inside a `ScrollViewer`. When that happens, the `ScrollViewer` will shrink in height (from the bottom up), it doesn't scroll at all, and some controls near the bottom of the viewport get covered up (cause the viewport is now smaller). If the `TextBox` gets covered up, I need to scroll such that it is still visible.

I have checked several SO questions, and none seem to capture my problem. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106624/calculate-a-scrollviewers-scrollbar-offsets-so-that-an-object-will-be-centered) is close, but I don't have a canvas to work with. Also, given my specific scenario, I **cannot** use `Dispatcher` to wait for the UI to load, and then use `BringIntoView()`.

The `TextBox`'s share an event, `TextBox_GotFocus`,

```
TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myScrollViewer.Height = 400; //used to be 600

    //if sender was in the 401-600 range, bring it into view
}
```

How do I scroll the `ScrollViewer` only if the entered `TextBox` is now hidden after the height change?

Answer (score 0):

No thanks to the random downvote, but I managed to figure a roundabout way to do this.

```
TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;

    //Get the distance from the top and bottom of the ScrollViewer
    double offsetTop = element.TranslatePoint(new Point(), myScrollViewer).Y;
    double offsetBottom = myScrollViewer.Height - offsetTop;

    //Get total height needed to show the whole element
    double height = 200 + element.Height;

    //If the control would be hidden...
    if (offsetBottom < height)
    {
        //Scroll down the difference
        double change = myScrollViewer.VerticalOffset + (height - offsetBottom);
        myScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(change);
    }

    myScrollViewer.Height = 400; //used to be 600
}
```